# Widget focusOutEvent event is called before button press inside widget

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, qt4

I have a class(MyWidget) inherited from QWidget and inside it I created a button and other widget (say W1), Both kept inside QVBoxLayout

On focusOutEvent widget(MyWidget) should hide and it works fine, but when I click the button inside the widget its getting hide but on clicking the widget (W1) inside the layout  its not hiding

```
m_layout = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
m_clearButton = new QPushButton(widget);
m_layout->addWidget(m_clearButton,0,Qt::AlignRight)

// this widget on click main widget is not hiding
m_layout->insertWidget(m_layout->count() -1,item);
```

Why button click hides MyWidget

Comment: Please, be more specific. Which widget should hide? And which one gets that "focus out" event?

Comment: Updated the description